# Should edit approvals work differently?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have decent rep here.  Frequently I'll edit someone else's question, for example to fix code formatting, which newbies often have trouble with.  But sometimes, as just now, I'll find that (a) someone else has already made the same edit, but (b) their edit has been deemed to require approval, which (c) my vote on is *not* sufficient, since additional approval is required!

So for now the question remains broken -- I can't fix it, and since I can't fix it I can't even easily read it (which makes it a sufficient nuisance to answer that I probably won't).  This seems wrong.  If I had been the first to edit, I could have done so singlehandedly, but because (I assume) a lower-rep editor happened to come along first, I can't.

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819998/how-to-fix-segmentation-error-in-c-while-implementing-recursive-binary-searc), although it will probably be fixed by the time you see it.

Comment: You can choose "Improve and Edit" to approve it directly, if there are more things to fix in a post.

Comment: @yivi More to the point, evidently the workaround is that I can choose "Improve and Edit" even if there *aren't* more things to fix.

Comment: True, although it's not in good form, IMO.

Comment: I was afraid this would be a duplicate, as it was, but the exact same thing already happened again, and have to say, the current behavior is broken.  [Latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822756/advanced-number-pattern).  Because there's a pending edit, I can't even *see* the raw form of the OP's question.  I tried the workaround of approving with edits and then clicking "okay", but the system scolded me for not making any edits, so now although it recorded my approval, I *still* can't immediately see what the OP was trying to do.